# django-filter checkbox submit

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-filter

I am using `django-filter==2.1.0` for implementing search filter. I already implement it. But now i need to search by clicking checkbox not by search button. My codes are given below:

**models.py**

```
class Book(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  publication = models.ForeignKey(Publication, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**filters.py**

```
class BookFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    publication = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(queryset=Publication.objects.all(),
                                                           widget= forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ['publication']
```

**views.py**

```
def test_view(request):
    book_list = Book.objects.all()
    book_filter = BookFilter(request.GET, queryset=book_list)
    temp = book_filter.form
    return render(request, 'test.html', {'filter': book_filter})
```

**template**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}

{% block content %}

    <form method="get">

        {% for choice in filter.form.publication %}

            <label>
                {{ choice.tag }}
                <span class="max-content-width">{{ choice.choice_label }}</span>
            </label>

        {% endfor %}
        <button type="submit">Search</button>

    </form>


    <ul>
        {% for book in filter.qs %}
            <li>{{ book.name }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

{% endblock %}
```

It's working properly. But i want to add `widget = forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'onclick': 'this.form.submit();'})` in my `filters.py` for checkbox input. I don't understand how can i add another widget. Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Create a [widget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/media/), write JavaScript script and use **Media** metaclass on widget to use it. After this just use your widget on your checkbox field.